# Dynamically(programmatically) generate Actors in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Actor system is stunning. I wonder if I can make it more flexible to use.

Saying I have a series of related node pairs (may in form of a file) like:

- A --> B
- B --> C
- C --> [D, E]
- D --> E
- E --> F

I want to generate a system containing 6 kinds of actors namely A~F programmatically when the server starts up. And they have supervisor-children relationship just like the pairs above tell.

Does this possible to Akka?

**EDIT 2014-05-28**

Sorry for the confuse.

I'm new to Akka, and some of the concept I learned so far might not be so accurate.

The real use case is that I want to generate an actor system using a config file which contains the relationship between actors. And each kind of actors have their strategy to deal receiving message.
As @cmbaxter put here, given actor can only have one supervisor, so let's just simplify the problem, saying I have a file contain actor relations such as

- A --> [B, C]
- B --> D
- C --> [E, F]

Based on this, I want to generate a system programmatically as:

```
      A
     / \
    B   C
   /   / \
  D   E   F
```

And I want each of A~F to have routers so that I am able to not create actors after this system is built. I know router might create actors under the hood, but I surely don't want any actor is created by mistake.

Does this sound possible with Akka? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are insinuating that E needs to be a child of both C and D then no you cannot setup an Actor System with this structure. An actor can only have one direct parent to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: This question is very unclear.  What's your actual use case?

Answer (score 2):

Hierarchies like this are simply defined by creating actors from other Actors.

```
val a = system.actorOf(..., "a") ! PleaseCreate("b", "c")

// inside "a"
context.actorOf(..., "b") ! PleaseCreate("d")
context.actorOf(..., "c") ! PleaseCreate("e", "f")

// and so on
```

The receive method would simply:

```
 def receive = { case PleaseCreate(names) => names foreach { context.actorOf(..., _) }
```

Be sure to check out the official docs too: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Basically I don't need actor being created when server starts serving. So Sending "create message" to sub-actor could work out here, but not too safe for me. I am thinking passing Array[ActorRef] to the Props like:`val NodeA = system.actorOf(Props(new MySimulator("A", Array[ActorRef](NodeB, NodeC)))`. But I'm not sure what side effect will be cause by this parttern.